# Linux knowledge: How do I practice Linux commands and different challenges?

Tags: command-line

I'm a DevOps Engineer by profession, but a noob in Linux...I want to gain deeper knowledge in Linux, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

[OVERTHEWIRE](https://overthewire.org/wargames/)

OverTheWire is nice website designed for people of of various expertise to learn and practice Linux commands and security concepts. There are wide variety of challenges available.

[CTF365](https://ctf365.com/)

On CTF365 users build and defend their own servers while launching attacks on other users’ servers. If you are a beginner to infosec, you can sign up for a free beginner account and get your hands-on experience with some pre-configured vulnerable servers.

[HACKING-LAB](https://www.hacking-lab.com/index.html)

Hacking-Lab provides CTF challenges Just register a free account, setup vpn and start exploring the challenges they offer.

Comment: good websites, but probably for someone that already know basic Linux commands